# Run composer commands in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, putty

I am a beginner in AWS.
I created an Elastic Beanstalk PHP instance and uploaded my Laravel application which uses AWS RDS for the database and I need to run some commands to commands to migrate the database. I connect the corresponding EC2 instance using putty SSH.The shell prompt is pointing to somewhere else when I try to change directory to my project folder showing No such file or directory error which means I am not in the root folder which all my project folders are in, so how to change to my project folder or I don't know whether it can be done using putty.Help please

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the answer
install composer by running

```
$ sudo curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php
$ sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
```

and the project files are in /var/www/html folder so just run

```
cd /var/www/html/project-folder
```

and you are good to go